# Is it possible to have things defined and controlled inside a class, without being assigned in the "form" (outside the class) in VB?

Tags: vb.net

My problem:

I have a checkbox I use to control if certain textboxes are enabled or not, and I need to do this around 30+ times. I've named my textboxes numerically/sequentially (TB_name_1, TB_name_2, etc) so if I know the Checkbox name I know which textboxes are affected.

My question:

Can I make a class for my checkboxes that says "if this box is checked/unchecked, then enable/disable these 3 textboxes" without the class also having to be told which textboxes (finds them itself)?

Here's the copy/paste code I'm currently using (not a class, obviously). I change the first 2 values and the rest of the code solves itself. (PS - I see you laughing)

```
Private Sub T1_cb_c_1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles T1_cb_c_1.CheckedChanged

    'change here for current checkbox
    Dim b As CheckBox = T1_cb_c_1

    'change here for start value of first textbox (of 3), the next 2 will be in sequence
    Dim a As Integer = 1

    'How much of the below code can be moved to, and controlled from, a class?
    Dim a1 As Integer = a + 1
    Dim a2 As Integer = a + 2

    Dim TB_PtNum As TextBox = Me.Controls.Find("T1_tb_c_" & a, True).FirstOrDefault
    Dim TB_Qty As TextBox = Me.Controls.Find("T1_tb_c_" & a1, True).FirstOrDefault
    Dim TB_Seq As TextBox = Me.Controls.Find("T1_tb_c_" & a2, True).FirstOrDefault

    If b.Checked = True Then
        TB_PtNum.Enabled = True
        TB_Qty.Enabled = True
        TB_Seq.Enabled = True
    Else
        TB_PtNum.Enabled = False
        TB_Qty.Enabled = False
        TB_Seq.Enabled = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you looking for a generic method to enable/disable 3 textboxes linked to a checkbox (like a row of data that should not be edited if the user uncheck the checkbox at the start of the row)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [property Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Tag) for the related controls.
Suppose to set this property to the value "line1" for the first set of textboxes and on the checkbox that controls them. 
Next row of controls (checkbox+textboxes) will have the property set to "line2" and so on until the last row. (You can do this through the Winforms Designer or through code)

At this point you could have a single event handler for all your checkboxes

```
Private Sub onCheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles T1_cb_c_1.CheckedChanged, T2_cb_c_2.CheckedChanged, _
    ..... add other checkbox events here .......

    ' Get whatever checkbox has been clicked and extract its tag
    Dim b As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
    Dim tag = b.Tag.ToString()

    ' Find the textbox controls in this form with the same Tag
    Dim ctrls = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Where(Function(x) x.Tag.ToString() = tag)

    ' Enabled status matches the status of the Checked property
    For Each c as TextBox in ctrls 
       c.Enabled = b.Checked
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: "At this point you could have a single event handler for all your checkboxes" - This is the ultimate goal of what I am trying to accomplish, I was only attempting the 'class' route because I haven't used them much (at all) and thought it'd be interesting to try.

Comment: Golden rule - K.I.S.S. Keep It Simple and Stupid Yes, you can have a single event handler for all your checkboxes. Just add the list of CheckBoxes.CheckedChanged events to the handler.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a design time only class that will do this.  You only have to the AssociatedCheckbox property in the designer:

```
Public Class TextBoxWithCheckboxProperty
    Inherits TextBox

    Private m_CheckBox As CheckBox

    Public Property AssociatedCheckBox As CheckBox
        Get
            Return m_CheckBox
        End Get
        Set(value As CheckBox)
            If Not m_CheckBox Is Nothing Then
                RemoveHandler m_CheckBox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf OnCheckBoxChanged
            End If
            m_CheckBox = value
            If Not value Is Nothing Then
                AddHandler m_CheckBox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf OnCheckBoxChanged
            End If

            OnCheckBoxChanged(m_CheckBox, Nothing)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub OnCheckBoxChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If Not sender Is Nothing Then
            Me.Enabled = CType(sender, CheckBox).Checked
        Else
            Me.Enabled = False

        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here's a sample Form1 that uses it:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.CheckBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox()
        Me.TextBoxWithCheckboxProperty1 = New WindowsApp4.TextBoxWithCheckboxProperty()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'CheckBox1
        '
        Me.CheckBox1.AutoSize = True
        Me.CheckBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(293, 131)
        Me.CheckBox1.Name = "CheckBox1"
        Me.CheckBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(81, 17)
        Me.CheckBox1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.CheckBox1.Text = "CheckBox1"
        Me.CheckBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'TextBoxWithCheckboxProperty1
        '
        Me.TextBoxWithCheckboxProperty1.AssociatedCheckBox = Me.CheckBox1
        Me.TextBoxWithCheckboxProperty1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(428, 131)
        Me.TextBoxWithCheckboxProperty1.Name = "TextBoxWithCheckboxProperty1"
        Me.TextBoxWithCheckboxProperty1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
        Me.TextBoxWithCheckboxProperty1.TabIndex = 1
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBoxWithCheckboxProperty1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.CheckBox1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.PerformLayout()

    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents CheckBox1 As CheckBox
    Friend WithEvents TextBoxWithCheckboxProperty1 As TextBoxWithCheckboxProperty
End Class
```